# Sencha Touch 2: Two REST request in the same Store

Tags: ajax, json, rest, extjs, sencha-touch

Is possible to include somehow multiple rest/json request in the same store?

For example I have this api that return json objects:

http://api1.domain.com

```
{"name":"john"},{"name:"harry"}
```

http://api2.domain.com

```
{"name":"peter"},{"name:"fred"}
```

I want to merge the results from api1 and api2 into one store in order to process it in a single view all concatenated. Result:

```
{"name":"john"},{"name:"harry"},{"name":"peter"},{"name:"fred"}
```

Or maybe not concatenated but I can show in a single view calling this two api at the same time:
john
harry
peter
fred

Is this possible?

I'm trying this with no success:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'sencha',
    views: ['Main1'],
    models:['AdModel'],
    stores:['AdStore1','AdStore2'],
    launch: function () {

    var store1Obj = Ext.getStore('AdStore1');
    var store2Obj = Ext.getStore('AdStore2');

    store1Obj.each(function(record){
        var copiedRecord = record.copy();
    store2Obj.add(copiedRecord);
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
        fullscreen: true,
        store: store2Obj,
        itemTpl: '<tpl for="."><div><strong>{name}</strong></div></tpl>'
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you are using the wrong syntax for the `each` method of a `store` http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each

Then it is simple to add 2 different data sources together in the same store.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {

        // Set up a model to use in our Store
        Ext.define("User", {
            extend: "Ext.data.Model",
            config: {
                fields: [{
                    name: "name",
                    type: "string"
                }]
            }
        });

        // Setup the stores
        var myStore1 = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
            model: "User",
            data: [{
                "name": "john"
            }, {
                "name": "harry"
            }],
            autoLoad: true
        });

        var myStore2 = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
            model: "User",
            data: [{
                "name": "peter"
            }, {
                "name": "fred"
            }],
            autoLoad: true
        });

        // Loop through each record of store2 adding it to store1
        myStore2.each(function(item, index, length) {
            myStore1.add(item);
        });

        Ext.create("Ext.List", {
            fullscreen: true,
            store: myStore1,
            itemTpl: "{name}"
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/g6n